# Fatel Error Android NDK adding Eigen/Dense

Tags: android-studio, opencv, android-ndk, eigen, eigen3

I'm using this library for attendance monitoring app. https://github.com/Lauszus/FaceRecognitionApp

I extracted SDKs to OpenCV-android-sdk & Eigen3

I'm using following commands to set environment variables:

```
setx OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK C:/Users/...(my path)../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk

setx EIGEN3_DIR /path/to/eigen3 C:/Users/...(my path).../Eigen3

echo %C:/Users/...(my path)../OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk% %C:/Users/...(my path).../eigen-eigen-67e894c6cd8f%
```

My **Android.mk** fie:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES := on
include $(OPENCV_ANDROID_SDK)C:/Users/Amey/AndroidStudioProjects/DevAttendance/FaceRecognitionApp/app/src/main/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE := face-lib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/face-lib.cpp $(LOCAL_PATH)/FaceRecognitionLib/Facebase.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/FaceRecognitionLib/Eigenfaces.cpp $(LOCAL_PATH)/FaceRecognitionLib/Fisherfaces.cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/FaceRecognitionLib/PCA.cpp $(LOCAL_PATH)/FaceRecognitionLib/LDA.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(EIGEN3_DIR) $(LOCAL_PATH)/FaceRecognitionLib/RedSVD/include
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -ldl
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -std=gnu++11 -frtti -fexceptions

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I'm getting following error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
C:\Users\Amey\AndroidStudioProjects\DevAttendance\FaceRecognitionApp\app\src\main\cpp\face-lib.cpp
Error:(20, 10) fatal error: 'Eigen/Dense' file not found
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 2.354 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: I had the same problem, i currently use windows 10, and just added environment variables based on the project [readme](https://github.com/Lauszus/FaceRecognitionApp/blob/master/README.md). Then i restarted my system, so android studio and the whole system was refreshed. i don't know why it didn't work before but it's working now.